# MySQL query to return a string using a Public String method

Tags: java, mysql

I have the following code, which queries a MySQL database to check if the user is an administrator or not.

```
public String admin () 
{
   String username = loginUserTF.getText();
   String password = loginPassPF.getText();
   String query = "SELECT * FROM userinfo where username=? and password=?";

   try {
       connect.pst = connect.con.prepareStatement(query);
       connect.pst.setString(1, username);
       connect.pst.setString(2, password);
       connect.rs = connect.pst.executeQuery();
       String admin = connect.rs.getString("Administrator");
       return admin;
   } catch(Exception e){}
}
```

I know that the return statement has to be outside the try and catch block but then I am not able to return the `String` `admin`. What is a way around this?

Comment: return something else if there is exception.

Comment: What do you *want* to happen if an exception is thrown? Why don't you let the exception propagate to the caller? (I'd strongly advise against just catching `Exception`, by the way - catch a more specific exception, e.g. `SQLException`.)

Answer (score 1):

Just store the result in a variable and return it after the try block.

```
   public String admin ()
   {
       String result=null;
       String username = loginUserTF.getText();
       String password = loginPassPF.getText();
       String query = "SELECT * FROM userinfo where username=? and password=?";
       try{
           connect.pst=connect.con.prepareStatement(query);
           connect.pst.setString(1, username);
           connect.pst.setString(2, password);
           connect.rs = connect.pst.executeQuery();
           if (rs.next())
               result = connect.rs.getString("Administrator");
       }
       catch(Exception e){
       }

       return result;
   }
```

I would also suggest that you don't keep your catch clause empty. You should handle any exceptions you catch.

Comment: If then I use this method in another calss by calling it. Then result is equal to null. Why is this? Why will it not stay as either Y or N.

Comment: @BEE if the query returns nothing or an exception occurs,  you'll get null. First check if you got an exception

Comment: The exception that occurs is "illegal operation on empty set". I guess this occurs because I am calling this method from another jFrame and therefore the textfields for username and password are not being read. Any tips on how to get around this?

Comment: @BEE Are you saying that `loginUserTF.getText()` and `loginPassPF.getText()` return null/empty values? Why don't you pass `username` and `password` as arguments to your `admin` method?